# Join query producing 0 results?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a bit confused as to how this works, I think I have an idea, but I am not sure. I have two tables:

```
Student and Classes
```

The Student table looks like this:

```
StudentID Name FavoriteClass
```

The Classes table looks like this:

```
ClassId ClassName Subject
```

I have created a relationship between Student.FavoriteClass and Classes.ClassName. However, for the Student table, StudentID is the PK and the ClassId field is the PK for Classes.

I am guessing the reason I can't join these tables is because I am trying to join on fields that aren't keys. If this is the reason, do you guys have recommendations to fix this?

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT [Classes].[Subject] FROM Classes INNER JOIN Student ON  Student.[FavoriteClass].Value =  [Classes].[ClassName];
```

Note: [FavoriteClass].Value is required for Access queries and multi-valued controls.

So if my Student Table had for example:

```
1 Mark ENG-101
2 Chris CS-103
3 Mary MAT-101
```

And my Classes Table had like:

```
1 ENG-101 English
2 CS-103 Computer Science
3 MAT-101 Algebra
4 GS-102 Geography Studies
```

I want to get the Subject field of Classes where the FavoriteClass of the Student table aligns with the ClassName field of the Classes table.

Comment: Store classid for favorite class, not class name.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve]. Note that multivalued fields are often defined as lookup fields, so taking a screenshot of your field properties, especially the lookup tab on your multivalued field, is very relevant. With the information you've provided, the query should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the type of the multi-valued field is really a text type. I guess that it is a number (the `ClassId`), which would indeed make much more sense. So drop your relationship and (if you will) create a new one between `Student.FavoriteClass` and `Classes.ClassId`.

For your query, try this:

```
SELECT [Student].[Name], [Classes].[Subject] 
FROM Classes 
INNER JOIN Student ON Student.[FavoriteClass].Value = [Classes].[ClassId];
```

For more information, I suggest to read [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a).